# Need to move the vertical alphabet in ios list to left of UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a custom app which displays users songs in a table view. I want to re-position the alphabetical index selection, that lets you jump to songs starting with a certain letter, to the left side of the table view.

Is it possible reframe the selection view? or is there a custom solution?

Comment: Where does the vertical alphabet come from if you _don't_ use a table view?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If the alphabet is in a UIView, can't you just adjust the frame so it appears on the left and not the right?  Or are the letters themselves in the wrong place *inside* the UIView containing the alphabet?  Same solution should apply either way, I should think.

Answer (score 0):

I have made alphabet scroll for UITableView check it out here http://blog.curiologix.com/custom-alphabetic-scroll-for-uitableview/